# How to fix my 2d array code that will be transfer to java uses JNI?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

i have trying to pass array from c++ to java. no error in compilation. but failed to run (crash). when i debug the code, error occurs in return code

i try to implement this code [how to return c++ char 2d array using JNI to JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551446/how-to-return-c-char-2d-array-using-jni-to-java)

here is my code

```cpp
    JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL my_function();
```

```cpp
    // ...
    // some code
    // ...

    // i want convert float point[3][2] to java

    jclass intArray1DClass = env->FindClass("[I");
    jclass intArray2DClass = env->FindClass("[[I");

     //  float point[3][2]
     jint sizeX = 3;
     jint sizeY = 2;


    jobjectArray array2D = env->NewObjectArray(
                sizeX, intArray2DClass, NULL);

    for (jint i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    {
        jobjectArray array1D = env->NewObjectArray(
                    sizeY, intArray1DClass, NULL);

        for (jint y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
        {
            jfloatArray value = env->NewFloatArray(point[i][y]); // float point[3][2]
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(array1D, y, value);
        }

        env->SetObjectArrayElement(array1D, i, array1D);
    }

    return array2D;
```

and this is how i call function from java. is it right?

```java
     float[][] point = my_function()
```

thank you

**Update**

Finally i use 1D array because its simple to write the code. and according to [1D or 2D array, what's faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster) , we should use 1D array

```cpp
     jint sizeX = 6;

     jfloatArray array1D = env->NewFloatArray(sizeX);

     env->SetFloatArrayRegion(array1D, 0, sizeX, point);


     return array1D;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks like you declaring Java array of ints, i.e. `int [][]`, not `float[][]`.

Second, why you set `jfloatArray` as element of your array? It should be simple float.

Third, in last line you probably meant `env->SetObjectArrayElement(array2D, i, array1D);`

Fourth, when you declaring array you need to specify class which it contains, so for 2D array it contains 1D array and for 1D array it contains just floats.

PS: Linked question/answer is actually returning 3D array. So you need to reduce number of dimensions in you code.